# How to execute database query in the middle of Jmeter script and use the retrieved data as a verification code?

Tags: sql, performance, jmeter, performance-testing, jmeter-5.0

Good evening.!

My scenario is, first I'd like to know record Jmeter script for user sign Up flow, but here we have to enter OTP which actually available in SQL Database.

So I'm trying to insert JDBC Request database query before the OTP Verification request. Need to get the code and pass it to the next API call as parameter.

I tried, Looks everything is perfect but facing one issue, The below message is the response.

***Response message: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot open server "DESKTOP-6MJTGIG" requested by the login.  The login failed.)***

I did some R&D Few people said, issue with query, but here in my case there is no issue with database query.

Here is few screenshots for reference.

[image: IMG_jdbc_Connection]
[image: IMG_JDBC_Request]
[image: Result_Img]
[image: Img_RequestQuery]
[image: OutputResponse]

Please, let us know the solution/what could be the reason for this issue.

Great thanks,
Rajesh Bathula

Comment: Most people here want formatted text instead of images. (And I can't read that tiny image text...)

Comment: Change max number of connections to 1

Comment: Facing new issue: 

Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (The TCP/IP connection to the host sql-server-stg-dev-local.database.windows.net, port 1433 has failed. Error: "connect timed out. Verify the connection properties, check that an instance of SQL Server is running on the host and accepting TCP/IP connections at the port, and that no firewall is blocking TCP connections to the port.".)


Something like abovew.

Comment: Other thing is: when i use other database with same setup it's working. Only for this database we're facing issue. Which actually in Azure cloud. so is there any security reason ??  for below isse:


Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Cannot open server "DESKTOP-6MJTGIG" requested by the login.  The login failed.)

Answer (score 0):

For handling OTP, you can try using `org.jboss.aerogear.security.otp.Totp` library.

To use it, you need to have in first place user key.
Then using a JSR223 PreProcessor, generate OTP.

Example:

```
import org.jboss.aerogear.security.otp.Totp;

public static String getOtp(String secret) {
    Totp generator = new Totp(secret);
    String result = generator.now();
    return result;    
}

String secret = Parameters;
log.info(secret);
String otp = getOtp(secret);
vars.put("otp", String.valueOf(otp));
log.info("OTP:"+ otp);
```

Take a look at this image.

[image]